# Perl oneliner corrupts file in Windows (carriage-return related issue)

Tags: regex, windows, perl, carriage-return

I have a PostScript file, in which I want to change one line from:

> %%Title: my abc

to

> %%Title: your def

The following Perl oneliner did the trick in Ubuntu:

```
perl -p -ifoo.bak -e "s/%%Title:.+\n/%%Title: your def\n/" file.ps
```

but it corrupts the file in Windows (looks like it adds \r\n to every "line" or something like that).

I tried another approach, but still no luck in Windows:

```
perl -Mopen=OUT,:bytes -p -ifoo.bak -e "s/%%Title:.+\n/%%Title: your def\n/" file.ps
```

What is going on and how do I solve that problem? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to touch the `\n`? Is `s/%%Title: \K(.+)/your def/` not good?

Comment: @zdim, because in general I don't know what initial title I have in a file and I want to change it. (think about doing this task for many files with different titles)

Comment: Oh, right --- I meant can you not leave out the newline, `s/%%Title: old/%%Title: new/`?

Comment: @zdim, of course it will be better to leave off carriage-return untouched, yes, i.e. substitute only the text.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line break from pattern and replacement:

```
perl -p -ifoo.bak -e "s/%%Title:.+$/%%Title: your def/" file.ps
```

or capture and use it in replacement:

```
perl -p -ifoo.bak -e "s/%%Title:.+(\R)/%%Title: your def$1/" file.ps
```

`\R` stands for any kind of line break.

If you want to transform whatever the actual line break is to unix linebreak (ie.`\n`):

```
perl -p -ifoo.bak -e "s/%%Title:.+\R/%%Title: your def\n/" file.ps
```

Comment: unfortunately it corrupts the file (both versions). I might provide the file if you want. I am not sure if it is relevant: the file was created in MacOs.

Comment: Nope.  The problem is not in the replacement but in the default layers used by perlio.

Comment: @tjd could you explain it a bit?

Answer (score -1):

In windows end of line are \r\n and not \n like in unix
so

```
perl -p -ifoo.bak -e "s/%%Title:.+\r\n/%%Title: your def\r\n/" file.ps
```

may works

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. It  corrupts the file. But I'll recheck it later and write back.

Comment: Nope.  The problem is not in the replacement but in the default layers used by perlio.